# Make visible a text box based upon input of a combo box using a lookup that stores multiple values

Tags: vba, ms-access

my first ever attempt at VBA and I'm struggling with this little challenge 
I can make it work when using a combo box getting the values from another table, but when I use the lookup and allow it store multiple values it gives me run-time error '13' Type mismatch

```
Private Sub DEPARTMENT_AfterUpdate()    
    If Me.DEPARTMENT = "BAR" Then
        Me.test3.Visible = True     
 End If         
End Sub
```

Here's the little bit of code I'm using 
Can I ask is it possible? if so could someone point me in the right direction

Many thanks

Comment: I suppose `Me.DEPARTMENT` is either not a string or `Me.test3` has no property visible. Hard to tell without more infos

Comment: you could try `me.department.value ="bar"`

Comment: Ooooh LiamH I thought you had it then, but no its still not working

Comment: What is "it" when you say " it gives me run-time error '13' Type mismatch" - can you point to the specific line that generates the error? What type of control is "DEPARTMENT" - is that the combo box?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this clearly, you have a combobox and a textbox on a form. You want the textbox to become visible depending on what is selected from the combobox list?

If that is the case then in form load:

`Private Sub Form_Load()
     Me.txtboxname.Visible = False
End Sub`

In combobox click event:

`Private Sub comboboxname_Click()
     If Me.comboboxname.ListIndex = 0 Then
          Me.txtboxname.Visible = True
     ElseIf Me.comboboxname.ListIndex = 1 Then
          Me.txtboxname.Visible = True
     Else
          Me.txtboxname.Visible = False
End Sub`

The numbers that correspond with the ListIndex are in order from top to bottom. 0 is typically the first selection on the combobox list. Play around with the numbers to make sure it works the way you want it to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi JB28 Yes thats it exactly thank you i have manged to make this work on a test form :) can I ask if I would like to store multiple values from the combo box and have text boxes hidden until selected would the code differ greatly, because I can't seem to make it work - have played with the comboboxname.value = 0 then.... and had a look to see how to reference multi value fields, but no joy, thanks for your time. S

Comment: Are you storing the selected values as new records in a table?

Comment: In the on click events of each combobox, you might want to try making the textboxes you want/don't want hidden by using the .Visible property. You could also use the .Enabled property to show the textboxes but keep them locked and grayed out. Let me know how it works out for you or if you need further clarification.